# No debug de JavaScript do Firebug, como exibir a linha de código atual?

Tags: javascript

Durante o debug de JavaScript, enquanto a execução está parada, se eu navegar para outro arquivo no painel do Firebug, não consigo voltar para a linha de código que será executada em seguida (marcada em amarelo).

Se eu usar os comandos "Step Into", "Step Over" ou "Step Out", o painel exibe imediatamente a linha seguinte, de acordo com o comando usado, mas aí a linha que estava marcada já foi executada.

A solução que encontrei foi, antes de sair da linha marcada, colocar um ponto de interrupção nela, e usar a lista de pontos para voltar depois.

É possível retornar à linha de código atual sem dar nenhum "Step" ou usar pontos de interrupção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vá na aba Pilha e clique no primeiro item:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

No meu caso, consigo voltar para o ponto atual do código clicando no último item da barra principal que fica dentro da aba "Script". Ele normalmente mostra o nome da função que você está debugando no momento. Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona independente do arquivo que você estiver no momento.

Comment: Isso funciona se você trocar de arquivo pelo botão que lista os scripts carregados, mas se você clicar em algum objeto de outro arquivo no console, essa lista de itens some. Não sei se isso é intencional, mas só por isso que marquei a outra resposta como certa: a aba Pilha sempre exibe essa opção, independente de como você troca de arquivo.

Comment: Bom saber! Não tinha testado dessa forma (somente troquei arquivos pelo console). A opção do Miguel Angelo não funciona para mim, já que não está aparecendo o "22 (linha 1072)" no meu Firebug. Acho que é porque estou usando o Mac OS e deve ter alguma diferença entre as versões. Abraços!